# Display pages with specific tag in Django

Tags: html, django, wagtail

i'am using bootstrap Tab panes and i need to show posts with specific tag in each pane without reloading the page of course 
for more detail i'm using Django with Wagtail CMS my app based on models file

**EDIT** : add tag dict to context

models.py:

```
class BlogIndex(Page):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    def get_context(self, request):
      base_tags = ['foo','boo','voo']
      # Update context to include only published posts, ordered by reverse-chron
        context = super(BlogIndex, self).get_context(request)
        blogpages = self.get_children().live().order_by('-first_published_at')
        context['blogpages'] = blogpages
        context['base_tags'] = base_tags
        return context

class BlogPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey('BlogPage', related_name='tagged_items')

class BlogPage(Page):
    #info
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)
    #contentpanel ....
```

note: i am using taggit but it seems that i didn't well handle it

blog_index.html

```
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    {% for tag in base_tags %}
    <li role="presentation" ><a href="#{{tag}}" aria-controls="{{tag}}" 
      role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{tag}}</a></li>
     {% ednfor %}
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
   {% for tag in base_tags %}
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="{{tag}}">
    #this is what i'am thinking of 
    #for posts in blogpages :
    # if post tag == "{{tag}}":
    # show post
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you construct a dictionary of tags and their corresponding pages in the `get_context` method of your `BlogIndex` class? This will be more efficient and less code then splitting in the templates by `if` statements

Comment: yes  i have one just i like to write it in the simple way first  to know how it work then i will replace it by for statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a few specific tags, you can call them in the template by define them below.

On the other hand if tags will increase continuously, It might be better to create a new model for tags.

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        all_list = Post.objects.all()
        news_list = Post.objects.filter(tag='news')
        context = {
            'all_list': all_list,
            'news_list': news_list,
        }
        return context
```

**Edit:**

You can show like this;

```
{% for object in news_list %}
 {{ object.title }}
 {{ object.timestamp }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: but  i need to know how to write the control statement to check if the page has the specific tag  to show it , i edited my qs and added the tags dict

Comment: I edit/update my answer for your ask. You can show your query like this.